# Change Windows Logon

Tags: django, face-recognition, winlogon, windows-credential-provider

I was researching how I could change Windows credentials to personalized ones, I saw that in old versions of Windows they used **Gina**, but now with Windows 10 we have to use the **Credential providers**, and I'm not a good understander of Windows, but the company where I'm interning told me to create a Windows login with facial recognition, can you tell me if this is possible and if it's possible what to use?

Thank you very much

I already have a project in **Django** with **facial recognition** for web attendance with anti-spoofing with connection to the **Postgre** database, I don't know if I can, for example, use a web view

I already tried to create something with **Gina**, but I didn't get the expected result.

Comment: What about Windows Hello with face recognition option? https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-up-facial-recognition-to-sign-into-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, but I need to record the logs, and know who logged in and out of Windows, so I kind of don't know if it would be a good option